# inspecting cordova android app per usb with chrome devtools results in blank screen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

Debugging a Cordova webview running in Chrome on Android (Pixel / Android 8.1) via the USB connection in Chrome desktop browser (65.0.3319.0 (Offizieller Build) canary (64-Bit)) is not working. Attempting to inspect web pages running on the mobile device results in a blank page.

When I inspect the blank page that appears in the desktop Chrome browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: InspectorFrontendHost.isUnderTest is not a function  
    at Object.Host.isUnderTest (inspector.js:930)  
    at Main.Main._gotPreferences (inspector.js:8301)  
    at DevToolsAPIImpl.embedderMessageAck (devtools_compatibility.js:33)  
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you file it to https://crbug.com/new?

Comment: I have the same problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an issue for me in Chrome Version 65.0.3315.4 (Official Build) dev (64-bit).

I installed an older version of Chrome [here](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable), which allowed me to move forward while the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801835) is investigated and resolved.